# an error occurred while opening that folder on the ftp server

Tags: linux, ftp, pureftpd

I created ftp server by pureftpd on linux sever:

```
sudo apt-get install pure-ftpd
sudo bash
echo "yes" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Daemonize
echo "yes" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/NoAnonymous
echo "yes" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ChrootEveryone
echo "yes" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/IPV4Only
echo "no" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ProhibitDotFilesWrite
```

but when I try to access to ftp from file explorer in Windows 10 by `ftp://x.x.x.x` with username and password I get this error:

an error occurred while opening that folder on the ftp server
[image: FTP folder Error]

I gave the all permission to root folder,
I add this line to configuration:

```
echo "10000 60000" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PassivePortRange
sudo systemctl restart pure-ftpd
```

but still I get the same error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use of other ftp servers have shown the same client-side result.  To access certain directories on the server via ftp, there are often multiple requirements.  After the client provides a user and password that are valid on the target host:

Various ftp servers often need additional configuration that allows access to specific directories.  Sometimes there's a global setting that lists 1+ directories that applies to all client access, eg "/ftp".  Another variety requires creating named ftp group(s), specifying 1+ directories accessible to that group, and adding users to 1 or more groups.

Although not always well documented, ftp servers tend to provide logging with any connection or session.  Check on the ftp server host for more detailed error information in a place like /var/log/messages.  Enabling session or error logging and the log-file location may be additional configuration settings.  If there's nothing obvious, file locations can sometimes be discovered with a cmd-line similar to this:

```
strings /usr/etc/ftp-server | grep /
```

Also remember to restart your ftp server after config changes.  Some network daemons are known to re-read config files after receiving a SIGHUP, eg:

```
pkill -1 server-name
```